# What's the expected number of unit-length cars being able to park in a street of length x?

Tags: probability

**Problem.** Motor cars of unit length park randomly in a street in such a way that the centre of each car, in turn, is positioned uniformly at random in the space available to it. Let $m(x)$ be the expected number of cars which are able to park in a street of length $x$. Show that

$$m(x+1)=\frac1x\int_0^x\{m(y)+m(x-y)+1\}\,dy$$

---

**My Attempt.** My only idea is that when the street length is some positive integer $s\geq2$, we can look for the lower bound of the number of parking cars by experimenting the smallest positive integer, say $i$, such that $\frac{s-i}{i+1}$ is less than 1; the upper bound is $s-1$. When I wanted to dig deeper by thinking about movable ranges for cars with a constant number of them, I was puzzled.

---

**Comment.** I just need some hint so that I have some space to think on my own. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze what $m(y) + m(x-y) + 1$ might mean. $m(y)$ is the expected number of cars at the segment of length $y$, $m(x-y)$ is the expected number of cars at the segment of length $x-y$ and $1$ is just one additional car. So the formula suggests we took a segment of length $x$, split it at position $y$, inserted a car of length $1$ there and fill the segments before and after ($y$ and $x-y$) randomly. Can you finish the logic?